# Variable number of arguments to sql.Query

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to pass a variable number of arguments to db.Query() in Go. I'm doing something like:

```
var values []interface{}
query := []string{"SELECT * FROM table"}
sep := "WHERE"

if ... {
    values = append(values, something)
    query = append(query, fmt.Sprintf(` %s field_a=$%d`, sep, len(values))
    sep = "AND"
}

if ... {
    values = append(values, something)
    query = append(query, fmt.Sprintf(` %s field_b=$%d`, sep, len(values))
    sep = "AND"
}

// Add an arbitrary number of conditional arguments...

rows, err := db.Query(strings.Join(query, " "), values...)
```

The query looks fine, and the values are all there, but I'm not getting anything back from the query. Some of the values are integers, some strings. When I manually try the exact same query (copy/paste) in psql, I substituting the actual values for $1, $2, etc, I get correct results. What am I missing?

**Edit**

Here's an example of what the final query (the result of `strings.Join()`) should look like:

```
SELECT
    table1.field1, table1.field2, table1.field3,
    table2.field4, table2.field6, table2.field6
FROM table1, table2
WHERE
    table1.field2=$1 AND
    table2.field3 IN ($2, $3)
```

When I try:

```
SELECT
    table1.field1, table1.field2, table1.field3,
    table2.field4, table2.field6, table2.field6
FROM table1, table2
WHERE
    table1.field2='something' AND
    table2.field3 IN (40, 50)
```

from `psql`, it works fine. When I call:

```
var values []interface{}
values = append(values, "something")
values = append(values, 40)
values = append(values, 50)
db.Query(`SELECT
    table1.field1, table1.field2, table1.field3,
    table2.field4, table2.field6, table2.field6
FROM table1, table2
WHERE
    table1.field2=$1 AND
    table2.field3 IN ($2, $3)`, values...)
```

from Go, I get a Rows object that returns `false` the first time `rows.Next()` is called, and a nil error.

Comment: Try to check result of `strings.Join` and then check resulting query. If driver can't show it to you, turn on logging all queries on your test pgsql db instance.

Comment: Show us the result of `strings.Join(query, " ")` to see what you are actually sending to `db.Query()`

Comment: This is an SQL-injection nightmare. Give us a few examples of what you want your resulting query to look like. If you want an IN clause, then that is super easy.

Comment: All of the values are internally generated from other database fields, so there's no SQL injection issue involved. I'll edit the question to show an example of what I want the query to look like.

Comment: What is the content of `err`? How if you execute the query with `db.Query(query, 'something', 40, 50)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "I get nothing"? What are the values of rows and err when you call `rows, err := db.Query(...`?

Comment: "I'm not getting anything back" -- I don't believe this for a moment. `Query` returns to values: `*sql.Rows` and `error`. Even if both of those are 'nil', you're getting _something_.

Comment: Here's the result of glog.Info(rows, err): &{0xc4201002a0 0x50c730 0xc420a56500 0x4f5840 <nil> {{0 0} 0 0 0 0} false <nil> []} <nil>

Comment: I clarified what I meant by "I'm not getting anything back".

Comment: Make sure you are connecting to the database you think you are. Also, check rows.Err() after rows.Next() returns false.

Comment: Found it. The problem turned out to be in the Scan(), not the return from Query(). Thanks for chiming in. In the process of following your suggestions, the code is now measurably better structured.